# How do I post a PDF?

Tags: media, javascript

I followed these steps to post a PDF file to Drupal.

1. Enable JSON API to create at  admin/config/services/jsonapi
2. Enable the media POST resource

   ```
   Media /media/{media}/edit: GET, PATCH, DELETE
         /entity/media: POST

   Methods: POST, formats: json: authentication: cookie
   ```
3. Create an Angular application and embed it in the Drupal page as a block

The Angular application captures the page using jspdf and embeds the image in the PDF. Instead of using an interceptor, I'm getting a token with each request.

```js
this.certificateService.getCsrf().subscribe(token => {
  this.certificateService.uploadMedia(pdf.output('blob'), fileName, token).subscribe({
    complete: () => {
      console.log('posted media');
    }
  })
});
```

`getCsrf()` grabs the token as text.

```js
getCsrf(): Observable<string> {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');

  return this.httpClient.get(this.host + '/session/token',{ headers: headers, responseType: 'text'}).pipe(catchError(this.handleError<any>('token')))
}
```

`uploadMedia()` tries to post the PDF file to media to Drupal.

```js
uploadMedia(pdf: Blob, name: string, token: string): Observable<any> {
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('certificate', pdf, name);
  const headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.set('Accept', 'application/vnd.api+json');
  headers.set('X-CSRF-Token',token);
  // headers.set('Content-Type','application/octet-stream');
  headers.set('Content-Type','application/hal+json');
  headers.set('Content-Disposition',`file; filename=${name}`);

  return this.httpClient.post(this.host + '/entity/media', formData, {headers: headers})
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('uploadMedia'))
    );
}
```

The error I get is *415 Unsupported media type*.

[image: 415 Unsupported media type]

I am using Angular 13 and Drupal 9.

I looked at the Drupal error log; it reports the following exception.

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnsupportedMediaTypeHttpException: No route found that matches "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryYAzO5lNTfgLQwQq9" in Drupal\Core\Routing\ContentTypeHeaderMatcher->filter()

Just setting the Content-Type header does not always alter the content type header that is posted. e.g. With both axios and angular http if you post a *FormData* array you will get a multi-part form even though you the header at the call level is application/octet-stream

Using axios within angular as follows result in 'application/octet-stream':

```
import Axios from 'axios-observable'; 
Axios.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-Token'] = token;
return Axios.post(this.host + '/entity/media', pdf, {
  headers: {
    Accept: `application/json, text/plain, */*',
    Authorization: `Basic ${basic}`,
    Cookie: ${cookie}; XDEBUG_SESSION=13681',
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
  }
});
```

Passing raw PDF data results in 'application/pdf'

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
return this.httpClient.post(this.host + '/entity/media', pdf, {headers: headers})
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError<any>('uploadMedia'))
);
```

Reviewing the rest services page *admin/config/services/rest*, the allowed content format is 'json'

Debugging confirms that symfony is checking this value

[image: Symfony accept JSON]

Trying a REST interface i.e. '/jsonapi/media/document/field_media_document/'

Yes there is a 'bin' content type requirement in web/core/modules/file/src/Plugin/rest/resource/FileUploadResource.php which

```
// Add the content type format access check. This will enforce that all
// incoming requests can only use the 'application/octet-stream'
// Content-Type header.
```

The */entity/media* JSON API request url does need a JSON request as per *web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/ContentTypeHeaderMatcher.php*

[image: entity media json request]

Answer (score 0):

I use Angular, not React, but I'm pretty sure this part is wrong:

```
  // headers.set('Content-Type','application/octet-stream');
  headers.set('Content-Type','application/hal+json');
```

Files need to be posted as `application/octet-stream`.  It's not a JSON object; it's a file.

Also, you may need to massage the PDF data into something that JSON:API understands.  For example, [here's the docs on doing this with axios/Node.js](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/file-uploads#s-tips-when-using-axios-or-other-http-client-libraries-and-nodejs).

In my case, for image files, I had to read the file in as a blob (React code, but may provide an example):

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/46568146
function readFileBlob(fileBlob: Blob) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      resolve(reader.result);
    };
    reader.onabort = () => Promise.reject(Error('file reading was aborted'));
    reader.onerror = () => Promise.reject(Error('file reading has failed'));
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileBlob);
  });
}

// fileToPost is a string that contains a blob:
// blob:http://localhost:8100/00507d3e-7f6f-4f48-be80-b55c8bc20dd3
const postAuthFileBlob = async (
  fetchUrl: string,
  fileToPost: string,
  // Fetch might return anything.
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
): Promise<any> => {
  const fileBlob = await fetch(fileToPost).then((res) => res.blob());
  const arrayStr = (await readFileBlob(fileBlob)) as ArrayBuffer;
  return postAuthFileBlobPart2(fetchUrl, arrayStr);
};
```

Comment: I think you are close. The back-end is complaining that the content-type is multipart/form-data instead of application/octet-stream

Comment: Just posting the pdf gives application/pdf  return this.httpClient.post(this.host + '/entity/media', pdf, {headers: headers}). Still drupal cannot find a match for application/pdf.  
No route found that        matches "Content-Type: application/pdf" in Drupal\Core\Routing\ContentTypeHeaderMatcher->filter()  
                                                    (line 49 of

Comment: @Interlated As I already stated, you need to post as `application/octet-stream`.  For some reason you commented that out in your code, but you have to post as `application/octet-stream` if you want to upload any binary files.